# IxNetwork python library: can't see traffic items in loaded ixncfg-file

Tags: python, tcl, traffic

I'm using IxNetwork python library for working with IxNetwork. After loading ixncfg-file with configuration, I can read via library ports, protocols, but not traffic items.

I want just load prepared ixncfg-file with all configration: ports, protocols, traffic items, flow groups. Start protocols; Regenerate traffic items; Apply changes in traffic items; Start traffic; Stop traffic after some time; Gather statistics

I'm stuck with traffic items. getList method for traffic return nothing - so I can't manipulate traffic items from ixncfg-file

```py
import IxNetwork
ixNServer = 'localhost'
ixNPort = '8009' 
ixNet = IxNetwork.IxNet() 
ixNet.connect(ixNServer, '-port', ixNPort) 
ixNet.execute('newConfig') 
fileName = r'/home/ccap/IxNetworkConfig.ixncfg' 
fileHnd = ixNet.readFrom(fileName) 
ixNet.execute('loadConfig', fileHnd) 
ixNet.execute('startAllProtocols') 

traffic = ixNet.getList(ixNet.getRoot(), 'traffic')
traffic_items = ixNet.getList(traffic[0], 'trafficItem') 

traffic_items list is empty

but it should return something like this:
['::ixNet::OBJ-/traffic/trafficItem:1',
 '::ixNet::OBJ-/traffic/trafficItem:2',
 '::ixNet::OBJ-/traffic/trafficItem:3',
 '::ixNet::OBJ-/traffic/trafficItem:4']
```

Comment: I have found root cause:
I have IxNetwork version 7.50, but working in python3 and install IxNetwork library by pip3 and it has version 8.5.
When I did the same steps in python 2.7 - traffic items are loaded correctly

Comment: No, problem was in this string:
`ixNet.connect(ixNServer, '-port', ixNPort)`

There is missed param '-version'
Correct connect line is:
`ixNet.connect(ixNServer, '-port', ixNPort, '-version', '7.5')`

In this case library 8.5 is working well with chassis 7.5